# Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem for Leibniz algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, universal-algebra, free-lie-algebras

Leibniz algebras can be seen as a non-skew-symmetric generalization of Lie algebras. I have already taken a look at some papers related to Leibniz algebras and extending main results of Lie algebras to Leibniz algebras. Here I want to ask you about the [Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9%E2%80%93Birkhoff%E2%80%93Witt_theorem) (PBW) theorem for free Leibniz algebras? Does the PBW theorem allow us to view a Leibniz algebra $L$ as a subalgebra of its universal enveloping algebra $U(L)$?

Comment: Googling for it: [Un Théorème de Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt pour les Algèbres de Leibniz](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/AGB-120017324) by Aymon and Grivel in Commun. Alg. 31 (2003);  [Poincaré–Birkhoff–Witt theorem for Leibniz algebras](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/223145297_Poincare-Birkhoff-Witt_theorem_for_Leibniz_-algebras), by Casas, Insua & Ladra in JSC 42 (2007)

Comment: The second reference should be to http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717107000995 ; note that its title has "$n$-algebras" instead of "algebras" (researchgate made a mistake here).

Comment: Also, Theorem 2.9 in: Jean-Louis Loday, Teimuraz Pirashvili, *Universal enveloping algebras of Leibniz algebras and (co)homology*, https://eudml.org/doc/165079 (also on http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~loday/PAPERS/93LodayPira(Leibniz).pdf ). Disclaimer: I've read none of the references (and, in fact, was only aware of two of them).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Oh I see, thanks for pointing this out! I was wondering why they repeated the same research after four years :D